# How to parse and access specific data in the HTTPresponse

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am new to swift and I want to develop a simple app to get data from a url. Right now I can get the JSON response from server, but I need all the data from it separately like email address, phone number and so on. So how could I get it?

This is the code which I am trying to get from

```
    var apple = "xyz123@gmail.com"
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://abcd.com/demo/xyzdemo/api/login?email_mobile=\(apple)")

    let response = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    response.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(response) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        //println("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString!)")

        var err: NSError?
        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {

            var loginDetails = parseJSON["UserLogin"] as? String
            println("Login Details: \(loginDetails)")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

and the string response I have got as an output is

responseString is as below =

```
{"UserLogin":[{"result":"Success",
"userid":111,"name":"test",
"email":"xyz@gmail.com",
"mobile":"12345893576",
"location":"mnop","img_url":
"http:\/\/abcd.com\/demo\/xyzdemo\/public\/images\/no_user.png",
"date_of_birth":"06-07-2015",
"date_of_anniversary":"22-08-2015"}],
"RelationDetails":[{"id":87,"user_id":111,"name":"abc@gmail.com","dob":"2015-08-04"},{"id":88,"user_id":111,"name":" qwe","dob":"2015-08-04"},{"id":89,"user_id":111,"name":" fags","dob":"2015-08-04"}]
}
```

firstNameValue: nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [SwiftyJSON-framework](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It's a great JSON-framework which makes your life a lot easier while working with JSON.

```
//Create JSONData:
var myJSON= JSONValue(data)
```

Then, to access for example the email, you can access the data like that:

```
let eMail = myJSON[0]["UserLogin"]["email"].string!
```

As you see, you take the first array-element(in your case there is only one) and search in the `UserLogin` leaf the element `email`. Then you take the string-value from it.

Comment: Worked fine for me, Thank you

Comment: Cool. Could you maybe accept the answer, so that other people can find it easier? (By clicking on the tick.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var loginDetails = parseJSON["UserLogin"] as? String
println("Login Details: \(loginDetails)")
```

try doing:

```
  if let loginDetails = parseJSON["UserLogin"] as? [String:String]
  {
      let email = loginDetails["email"]
      println("email is \(email)")
  }
```

What I'm doing here is instead of forcing "`UserLogin`" to be String object (which it isn't), I set it to be a dictionary with String keys and String object values.

Then we can fetch the e-mail string value out of that and print it out.

And you can do the same for the rest of the values in the "`UserLogin`" dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and taking suggestions by Michael Dautermann and Christian, I found this code to be useful. This code can be used only after we use SwiftyJSON.swift file in our project, which is available in https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

```
    var apple = "xyz123@gmail.com"

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://abcd.com/demo/xyzdemo/api/login?email_mobile=\(apple)")

    let response = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    response.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(response) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString!)")


        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        if data != nil {
            var hoge = JSON(data: data!)
            println(hoge["UserLogin"][0]["email"])
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```